# Google Document Viewer external URL

Tags: pdf, iframe, google-document-viewer

Is there a way to supply Google Docs Viewer with a source from a proxy download? Such as from https://www.url.com/download.php?file=fdg46fgd (random download code).

The download script headers look like this:

```
header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");

header("Content-Length: " . $size);
header("Cache-Control: private");
```

It prints the contents after the headers are established. This works fine when you enter the link into the browser and works as expected. I have also tried using inline instead of attachment but the Google Doc Viewer always displays "No Preview Available". The document viewer code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://www.url.com/download.php?file=fdg46fgd&embedded=true" style="width:800px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have tried using different documents such as pdfs, docx, etc.

If I use a direct link it will display properly, but not when using the download script. I have seen people using a download script based URL before and it seemed to work for them. Does this not work with Google Doc Viewer anymore? Any suggestions? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the process in your download URL have validation (ex: check login, limit user, ...).
Remove this validation code, Google Doc Viewer can be open file you want.